# Toolbar not showing at the top of the page in Tab Bar Based Application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar

In my iPhone app, I am using a tab-bar based application as my basic application type.

I created one toolbar at the **top** of the page in FirstViewController of tab-bar based app.

Also I changed File's Owner Class to "FirstViewController" aqnd have connected the outlets to toolbar buttons.

Now the problem is that when I run the project I don't see any toolbar at the top my page.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have u added the toolbar at the bottom of the page? If yes, then try to move it upwards (or may be just put it in the center for trial purpose). Please also check if it is not below any other view.

Comment: No I have added toolbar at the top of the page. and I have no other view in my project yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer.

All credit goes to **Madhup.**

Check **Madhup's** Comment below this Question. He is right because of tab bar the toolbar went out of the page and was hidden under status bar in iphone.

Tried moving it a little below and now I am able to see the toolbar. :)

Thanks Madhup!!

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

@PARTH how is it possible i had done the same u are asking.......and i am getting the toolBar at the `top` of the page in `FirstViewController` of tab-bar based app.

i suggest u to please check that your `toolBar` is not below any other view.

Comment: No toolbar is not below any other view as I have added nothing else to the view and there is no other view in my project rite now. Thanks for the input. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the view property "Bottom Bar" to "Tab bar" of the FirstViewController.

Answer (score 0):

This question either predates storyboards *or* the asker is using xib based views, but this is the first hit in my search result, so I'll add more info here.

If you're using **Storyboards**, go to your Navigation Controller and make sure that in the Attributes Inspector (View -> Utilities -> Show Attributes Inspector) the Top Bar is set to something. (And the Bar Visibility is set to show Navigation Bar).

By default it seems that even if you add a navigation bar to the top of an individual view, that it's the Navigation Controller that controls if that top bar is shown or not